# Two identical linux sd drives? Can I delete one?

Tags: linux, partitioning, centos-7

So I'm really new to linux and am learning as I go, building a FOG server. I recently connected my FOG server to an iSCSI NAS device. When I went to see the disk I want to partition, it looks like I have two copies or something. Can I delete one and why do I have two.

```
[   25.390122] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[   25.391593] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[   25.391837] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] 17488150528 512-byte logical blocks: (8.95 TB/8.14 TiB)
[   25.392079] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[   25.392083] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 77 00 00 08
[   25.392599] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: disabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[   25.393716] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[   25.420711]  sdb: unknown partition table
[   25.421463] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[   25.423684] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[   25.464766] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[   25.466368] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[   25.466836] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 17488150528 512-byte logical blocks: (8.95 TB/8.14 TiB)
[   25.467369] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[   25.467373] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 77 00 00 08
[   25.468057] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: disabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[   25.468843] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[   25.474337]  sdc: unknown partition table
[   25.475430] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[   25.476647] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[10997.260848] nfsd: last server has exited, flushing export cache
```

Comment: Any chance there is multipath there? Or mirror? Snapshot?